# How to remove attachments from multiple Outlook Mail Items at once?

Tags: vba, email-attachments, outlook-2013

I have searched for a solution to this, but no luck.  I know it will be code based, but I'm really not sure where to start with it.

Here is the problem:
Input: 1 zip file containing multiple (upwards of 50) separate "Outlook Items"
Each outlook item opens up into an email that has an attachment on it.
Output: 1 file with all attachments from the Outlook items inside of it.

Example:
input:
Myzip.zip ->

Mail_item1.msg

Mail_item2.msg

Mail_item3.msg

output:
MyOutputFile ->

mail_item1_attachment.pdf

mail_item2_attachment.pdf

mail_item3_attachment.pdf

any guidance is appreciated.  My only thoughts thus far are outlook VBA (can this access multiple .msg items in a folder on the C drive?)

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub get_attachments_from_mailItems()
Dim inPath As String
Dim outPath As String
Dim msg As MailItem
Dim doc As Attachment

'What do I dim the following as?
Dim input_folder
Dim output_folder
Dim attachments 'collection? array?

inPath = "C:\temp\input"
outPath = "C:\temp\output"

'--I need most help with the folder objects and how to create them/use them --

'Open input folder as object
'open output folder as object

For Each msg In input_folder
    'check message for attachments, then loop if there are
    For Each doc In attachments
        'Save attachment in output_folder
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. `1` Extract the zip to a temp folder `2` loop through the msg files `3` Open them in outlook `4` Download attachments. Give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and we will then take it from there.

Comment: Good to know it is possible without a batch file or something.  I posted what I have done so far, I'm having trouble finding the documentation relevant to filling in the blanks

Comment: No if you are doing this from VBA then you don't need a batch file. `1` To open Zip file from VBA see [THIS](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win004.htm) There are other links in the web.`2` To open msg file in outlook, see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220081%28v=office.11%29.aspx) `3` To download attachments see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781320/download-attachment-from-outlook-and-open-in-excel/11782153#11782153) Now you have almost every thing on the plate. Give it a try and then post back what you tried and we will then take it from there?

Comment: Can you clarify the information in the second link that helps me open msg files from a folder on my c drive?  
Here is the process I'm now going for:

Extract zip to "C:\temp\input".  Run macro. Have attachments in "C:\temp\output"

Macro:
Loop through msg files in "C:\temp\input"
for each msg, save attachment in "C:\temp\output"

Thanks to some information you provided and some I found online, I have general direction for everything except the looping part.

How could I access a folder on my c drive and loop through the unknown number of files in it?

Comment: Search google for `DIR`

Comment: my new code is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383290/how-do-i-open-an-outlook-msg-file-from-my-harddrive-that-is-not-in-outlook

I'm able to loop through the messages, but I can't open them.
I get a run-time error that the file cant be opened when i try to use .OpenSharedItem(<path to .msg file>)

Comment: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/remove-attachments-from-sent-messages/ ?