# Save Outlook attachment VBA does not work properly

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to run this code, but it does not save the xml file to the given folder. What is wrong with it?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat As String
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\xml\"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xml") Then
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
End If
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the extra "\" in `saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName` since you already have "\" in `saveFolder = "C:\Users\gabor\Documents\CAFM\xml\"`

Comment: You are right. I deleted it, but it still doesn't work. This code is in an Outlook rule. This rule saves the attachment from the email.

Comment: Try changing `objAtt.DisplayName` to `objAtt.Filename`

Comment: I did it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `itm.Attachments.Count` as shown in Part 2 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781320/download-attachment-from-outlook-and-open-in-excel/11782153#11782153) and then stepping through it. Does your code enter the relevant area?

Comment: The moved emails always have attachment at least one. This code is in the VbbaProject.OTM-Microsoft Outlook Objects-Module3 and the outlook rule refers to this macro.

Comment: Can you step through your code and check if it actually gets executed?

Comment: Changing the security settings solved the problem. I had to set the macro settings to enable all macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment "Changing the security settings solved the problem. I had to set the macro settings to enable all macro." – vergab Jul 28 at 20:09