# How to check for VBA7 in Office 365/x64?

Tags: excel, vba

At my job, VBA in Outlook is turned off. I've been using a Excel VBA code to store Outlook attachments.

In Windows 10 / Office 365 x64 / OneDrive I can't save the Excel file after adding the code.

The section of the code that when I add, the file won't save:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr
    
    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    
' *****************************************
' For the previous version of Outlook 2010.
' *****************************************
#Else
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As Long
    
    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Entire code:

```vb
Option Explicit

' *****************
' For Outlook 2010.    Tested ok on Outlook 365 x32 as well!
' *****************
#If VBA7 Then
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr
    
    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    
' *****************************************
' For the previous version of Outlook 2010.
' *****************************************
#Else
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As Long
    
    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

' The class name of Outlook window.
Private Const olAppCLSN As String = "rctrl_renwnd32"
' Windows desktop - the virtual folder that is the root of the namespace.
Private Const CSIDL_DESKTOP = &H0
' Only return file system directories. If the user selects folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
' Do not include network folders below the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = &H2
' The maximum length for a path is 260 characters.
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

' ######################################################
'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.
' ######################################################
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
    Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.
    Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.
    Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.
    Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.
    Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.
    Dim atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.
    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.
    Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.
    Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.
    Dim strFolderPath       As String       ' The selected folder path.
    Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.
    Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.
    
    blnIsEnd = False
    blnIsSave = False
    lCountAllItems = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        
        ' Get the handle of Outlook window.
        lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)
        
        If lHwnd <> 0 Then
                        
            
            ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Folder to store attachments in:", _
                                                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, "I:\My documents\OLAttachments")


            ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                       Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            End If

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                strFolderPath = ""
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            Else
                strFolderPath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)
                

                ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
                For Each objItem In selItems
                    lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count
                    
                    ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */
                    If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                        Set atmts = objItem.Attachments
                        
                        ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
                        For Each atmt In atmts
                            
                            ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtFullName = atmt.Filename
                            
                            ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.
                            intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")
                            
                            ' Get the name.
                            strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                            ' Get the file extension.
                            strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                            
                            ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & atmt.Filename
                            
                            ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/
                            If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
                                ' True: This attachment can be saved.
                                blnIsSave = True
                                
                                ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */
                                Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                    strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                      Format(Now, "_mmddhhmmss") & _
                                                      Format(Timer * 1000 Mod 1000, "000")
                                    strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)
                                        
                                    ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/
                                    If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                        lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                        ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.
                                        blnIsSave = False
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop
                                
                                ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */
                                If blnIsSave Then atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                            Else
                                lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    
                    ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
                    lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If
           
          
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
    End If
    
    
PROC_EXIT:
    SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems
    
    ' /* Release memory. */
    If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
    If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
    If Not (atmt Is Nothing) Then Set atmt = Nothing
    If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing
    
    ' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' #####################
' Convert general path.
' #####################
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' ######################################
' Run this macro for saving attachments.
' ######################################

Public Sub ExcelSaveOutlookAttachments()

    Dim lNum As Long
    
    lNum = SaveAttachmentsFromSelection
    
    If lNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachments was saved without any errors.", vbInformation, "Excel Message"
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no attachments to save in selected mails!", vbInformation, "Excel Message"
    End If
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious.. Why are you using APIs to download the attachment? Have you seen [Download attachment from Outlook and Open in Excel]?

Comment: I am for sure no pro code writer. I found this code online many years ago, changed a few linjes to support my need, and haven't given it any more thought... :-)  I will check it out.

Comment: I just noticed that I forgot to add the link... Here it is [Download attachment from Outlook and Open in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781320/download-attachment-from-outlook-and-open-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

> when I run it in 365/x64/OneDrive

The [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method of the `Attachment` class saves the attachment to the specified path, the method is not aware about OneDrive and designed to deal with a local file system. You can save the attached files to any local folder on the disk and then upload them to the OneDrive storage.

There are several aspects that I've found in your code after reviewing it:

1. The [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method may overwrite files with the same `FileName` value:

   ```
   atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
   ```

   To prevent this from happening you need to add any ID to the filename. For example, you may consider using the current time or just the `RecievedTime` property value of the `MailItem` to isolate items from different Outlook items.
2. Outlook folders may contain different kind of items, so the `Selection` object may include appointments, posts, documents, notes and etc. To make sure that you deal with a mail item you need to check the the `MessageClass` property value or just item type at runtime.
3. The following code make sense only if it is run in Outlook VBA:

   ```
   Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection
   ```

   Otherwise, you need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance and use properties of the `Application` class instead.

Finally, you may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this site:
[https://jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp][1]
I've found out that when changing the top bit of the code with the code below, it runs and does what it should do.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
#End If
```

Still got error when I'm trying to save my file saying:

> Could not save changes due to sharing permission violation. Try saving
> to a different file"

Looks like something for my job's IT dep.